# Adding maven dependency gives a specific error during my spring batch

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, maven-3

I am working on a batch and I face a problem. I have identified the cause of my issue but I am not able to solve it.

As soon as I add a dependency in my pom I start to get an error

The maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My pom is as shown below

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.edf.fr.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>edf-batch</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error I get is this

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.util.BeanDefinitionUtils.(BeanDefinitionUtils.java:53)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:54)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:176)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.edf.fr.batch.MarcheBatchApplication.main(MarcheBatchApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>     ... 12 common frames omitted
>
> 2017-08-14 16:18:43.676  INFO 11676 --- [           main]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@48a242ce:
>   startup date [Mon Aug 14 16:18:42 CEST 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy 2017-08-14 16:18:43.677  WARN 11676 --- [           main]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception thrown from
>   LifecycleProcessor on context close
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized -
>   call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@48a242ce:
>   startup date [Mon Aug 14 16:18:42 CEST 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.edf.fr.batch.MarcheBatchApplication.main(MarcheBatchApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]
>
> 2017-08-14 16:18:43.678 ERROR 11676 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with
>   name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
>   threw an exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not
>   initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the
>   context:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@48a242ce:
>   startup date [Mon Aug 14 16:18:42 CEST 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.edf.fr.batch.MarcheBatchApplication.main(MarcheBatchApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the given stacktrace you can see that some classes are not found, since you are using spring boot, spring boot uses meta dependencies which contains several dependencies, as mentioned in spring-boot-cookbook

> Spring    Boot    aims    to  simplify    the process of  getting started with    an  application creation.
>   Spring    Boot    starters    are bootstrap   libraries   that    contain a   collection  of  all the relevant
>   transitive    dependencies    that    are needed  to  start   a   particular  functionality

spring-data-jpa is not enough, there are some other dependencies you need, use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```